# Load the SDK Asynchronously without server web

Tags: facebook

I need to know if it's possible load the javascript SDK without a server web:

```
(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); 
     js.id = id; 
     js.async = true;
     js.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     console.log("1");
   }(document));
```

My problem is that the line  js.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'; doesn't load correctly because calls the url:

```
GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

and the response is Not Found.
If anyone know what can i do for load asynchronously the javascript SDK for Facebook without server web i would appreciate it.
Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Save the all.js file in your app directory and change the line:

```
js.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
```

to

```
js.src = 'your_app/js/all.js';
```

but have in mind that this is not a good method for production purposes, because you will not be able to follow any updates made from Facebook.